# Patch priority and its effect on Criminsi's Exemplar Based Inpainting

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to implement exemplar based in-painting, as proposed by [Criminsi](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67276/criminisi_tip2004.pdf) et. al. in its original format (before moving into further optimisations).

I have a few theoretical doubts which I would like to clarify.

I am not sure how the patch priority and the determination of fill-order works to propagate linear structures into the user-selected target region.

From what I understand, Criminsi suggests the following:

1. Determine the fill front dΩ.
2. Compute the patch priorities [C(p)D(p)] on patches lying on the fill
   front.
3. Propagate texture into the patches - in order of their patch
   priorities.
4. Update confidence values.
5. Re-compute fill front dΩ from the remaining unfilled section.

*[Repeat these 5 steps till all of the target region is filled].*

Now, if this understanding of the algorithm is correct (and, please do correct me if the interpretation is wrong), I have the following doubt:

- If I'm always filling patches from the fill front only, and if the
  patches are fixed in their spatial location (w.r.t other patches on
  the fill-front), then I don't see how the order of filling-in
  matters. The patches are filled in by direct sampling of the source
  region, which stays constant for all iterations. Hence, I do not
  understand how the order of filling will result in any pixel level
  difference on the propagated textures. From what I gather, the best match from the source region should remain unaltered, irrespective of the order. What am I missing here?
- Based on this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYk9_fTZbAs) (and assuming it is correct), the patch
  filling does not always occur on the fill-front only. How does this
  work?  Does this mean we are to compute the priorities for all patches in the target region at once and go on filling them based on their priorities? Then, how does the fill-front determination matter and why does Criminsi determine dΩ at all? I understand Criminsi's approach was a step ahead of the traditional onion-peel technique. But how, exactly?

I really wish to clarify these questions before I delve into 2-3 days of intense coding.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it better to post this somewhere else? stackoverflow?

Comment: did you get answer to all these questions? did you re-post your question somewhere else? I am also trying to understand the same method

Comment: @stalin: I worked on this long back. But I did complete this algorithm, and made a demo app from it: https://github.com/agnivsen/Exemplar  .... however, I'm still not 100% sure if I got the algo right. Beware of nasty hacks in the code. If you really want to look into it, start from Exemplar.m file and look into the method: 'exemplarWithMask'